# Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined Javascript

Tags: javascript, ssjs

Am getting an error Un-Caught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined Javascript.
I have added HTML & Javascript of the code below:

Am new to javascript please help!

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
    <form>
  EventID:<br>
  <input type="text" name="EventID" id="EventID"><br>
  Event Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="EventName" id="EventName"><br>
  Speaker Name :<br>
  <input type="text" name="SpeakerName" id="SpeakerName"><br>

</form>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script runat=server language="JavaScript" executioncontexttype="Post">

function myFunction() {
window.alert('Hi');
Platform.Load("Core","1.1");
 var a = document.getElementById("EventID").value ;
 var b =  document.getElementById("EventName").value ;
  var c = document.getElementById("SpeakerName").value; 


var de = DataExtension.Init('EMS_Events');
var result = de.Rows.Add({EventID:'a',EventName:'b',SpeakerName:'c'});
de.Rows.Lookup
Write('<b>Output:</b>'+result);
}

</script>


  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Check if you have actually added the cdn for the Platform library

Comment: Thanks for your reply Danyal. Am new may i know how to add cdn?

Comment: I am not sure which syntax does that library belong to, else I'd help you.